# Logged in user's context being used in a new conversation too while using botauth with Azure table storage

Tags: c#, azure-storage, botframework

I am using [BotAuth](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botauth/tree/master/CSharp) to login users on my bot. Recently I implemented Azure Table storage to store and manage bot’s state data, by following the steps mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state-azure-table-storage.

My Global.asax.cs file looks like this :

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
            Conversation.UpdateContainer(
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.RegisterModule(new AzureModule(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));

                    var store = new TableBotDataStore(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"], "botfactoryestimatorstate");
                    builder.Register(c => store)
                        .Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore)
                        .AsSelf()
                        .SingleInstance();

                    builder.Register(c => new CachingBotDataStore(store,
                                 CachingBotDataStoreConsistencyPolicy.ETagBasedConsistency))
                         .As<IBotDataStore<BotData>>()
                         .AsSelf()
                         .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
                    // Register your Web API controllers.
                    builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                    builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);

                });

            config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(Conversation.Container);
        }

        // WebApiConfig stuff
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config =>
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        });
    }
```

And **MessagesController** is same as the one in the bot template, no changes there.

On testing it in 2 emulator windows, one after the other, I notice that the first emulator prompts for login, while the other emulator window is taking in the context automatically, and not prompting in for authentication :
[image]

On Debugging it, I found that `context.UserData.TryGetValue($"{this.authProvider.Name}{ContextConstants.AuthResultKey}", out authResult)` code in botauth returns values always, after any user is authenticated.

But when I change from the state management in azure table to use the old state management by bot framework, I get the expected behavior.
[image]

What exactly am I missing? Is it some autofac module registration. Does anyone have a perfectly working sample for this.

Comment: I have an idea around this problem: is this coming from the fact that between 2 emulator you have the same UserId (`default-user`), so maybe pointing to the same botstate when using `context.userData` ?
Can you try to use context.PrivateConversationData instead to see if in that case you have the prompt for authentication in both cases?

Comment: It's happening even in 2 instances of web chat. Setting context.PrivateConversationData would mean to change the botauth code. But still, how come its working perfectly while using default bot framework state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that each instance of the emulator hosts its own state service.  When using a custom state client, the state is shared across all clients connecting (the emulator's state service is not used).  If the id of the user is the same (as it is across different emulator instances), a shared state retrieves the same UserData (as it should).

Note: this will not be an issue on channels other than the emulator and webchat, because the user's id is different.  This can be overcome in webchat by generating a unique UserId whenever BotChat is initiated:

```
<script>
      var uniqueUserId = getUniqueUserId();
      BotChat.App({
        directLine: { secret: direct_line_secret },
        user: { id: uniqueUserId  },
        bot: { id: 'botid' },
        resize: 'detect'
      }, document.getElementById("bot"));
</script>
```

<strike>https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botauth/commit/b6e9751eab8d9b3bc02274882e4042ba788f4dca has not been released to nuget yet.  The default state client is always retrieved in the CallbackController of the current botauth.  Context dialogs retrieve the autofac state client implementation. This inconsistency is what the above commit fixes. It should be released to nuget soon.</strike>

Comment: Thanks @eric-dahlvang for explaining in detail. I have implemented and it works perfectly, but I have few questions :  

  1. Your solution means to use direct line instead of the webchat iframe in case we are using our own custom state client, now as bot framework is moving to GA and since all are advised to use their own custom state client, won’t this pose a huge concern/issue to the existing webchat users. Also this means that we won’t be able to use webchat again.

Comment: 2.Secondly, I am returning a GUID in getUniqueUserId()  which means, on each browser refresh, a new userid would be generated and the user would have to login again using BotAuth. So I should think of using some cache mechanism to ensure the id is not lost and retained for some time. Is that right?

Comment: This issue you've raised here on Stack Overflow has nothing to do with a custom state client perse.  The issue is with how identity is handled in the webchat's iframed implementation.  Bots that do not require a login flow or UserData state can set CachingBotDataStoreConsistencyPolicy to LastWriteWins, and use the iframe.  Your bot is more complex, and requires tracking identity, so you should control the userid.